# Sorting a dict...efficient way to do it?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I've have the problem where I have a dict of the passengers like this:

```
passengers = {
              1: {'name': 'Foo', 'lastname': 'Bar', 'exclusive': True},
              2: {'name': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe'},
              3: {'name': 'Rocky', 'lastname': 'Balboa', 'exclusive': True},
              4: {'name': 'Mohammed', 'lastname': 'Smith'}
             }
```

And I need to print the results like this items with exclusive first then the rest:
**THIS IS THE DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
List of passengers:
===================
1.- Foo Bar
2.- Rocky Balboa
3.- John Doe
4.- Mohammed Smith
```

I tried with `collections.deque`, and I haven't found anything that works for me, until I came up with this function:

```
def prioritize_passengers(dictionary):
    priority_list = []
    normal_list = []
    sorted_list = []

    for key, item in dictionary.iteritems():
        if 'exclusive' in item:
            priority_list.append(key)
        else:
            normal_list.append(key)

    sorted_list = priority_list + normal_list

    return sorted_list
```

And then I use it on my data like this:

```
# Assuming passenger is the same var as above
sorted_list = prioritize_passengers(passengers)
print "List of passengers:\n==================="
for elem in sorted_list:
    passenger = passengers[elem]
    print "{} {}".format(passenger['name'], passenger['lastname']
```

Is that the only way to do it or is there a more clear/efficient way to achieve it? Again, the second paragraph is the desired output.

Comment: you can try OrderedDict https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html

Comment: I think you want to remember the order of your passengers, isnt it?

Comment: @VincentSavard Is more explicit now, that what I have is the first block, what I want is the second block, and what I did to achieve it is the 3rd and 4th block.

Comment: @AngelVelásquez I understand that, but I still don't know why it is ordered that way. I _guessed_ that you want exclusive items shown first, but you never explained it in your question. I can't guess anything else. Your desired output is not enough by itself.

Comment: Is there any order required among passengers of the same class? For example, does it matter if 'Foo Bar' comes before or after 'Rocky Balboa'?

Comment: @Robᵩ it doesn't matter I just want passengers with exclusive first than the rest. and then print them, that's it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are other ways to sort that list. Here is one:

```
passengers = {
              1: {'name': 'Foo', 'lastname': 'Bar', 'exclusive': True},
              2: {'name': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe'},
              3: {'name': 'Rocky', 'lastname': 'Balboa', 'exclusive': True},
              4: {'name': 'Mohammed', 'lastname': 'Smith'}
             }

list_of_passengers = sorted(
    passengers.items(),
    key=lambda x: (('exclusive' not in x[1]), x[0]))

for i, (_, passenger) in enumerate(list_of_passengers, 1):
    print '{}. - {} {}'.format(i, passenger['name'], passenger['lastname'])
```

Since you don't care about the order other than the `exclusive`-ness, then you this might work for you:

```
passengers = {
              1: {'name': 'Foo', 'lastname': 'Bar', 'exclusive': True},
              2: {'name': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe'},
              3: {'name': 'Rocky', 'lastname': 'Balboa', 'exclusive': True},
              4: {'name': 'Mohammed', 'lastname': 'Smith'}
             }

list_of_passengers = sorted(
    passengers.values(), key=lambda x: 'exclusive' not in x)

for i, passenger in enumerate(list_of_passengers, 1):
    print '{}. - {} {}'.format(i, passenger['name'], passenger['lastname'])
```

Finally, if what you really want to do is to create two separate lists, you can use the `filter()` builtin funciton:

```
upper_crust = filter(lambda x: 'exclusive' in x, passengers.values())
riff_raff = filter(lambda x: 'exclusive' not in x, passengers.values())
```

Comment: Thanks! the key + function on sorted helped me.